# sumo-launchd.py sumo checking

Tags: veins, sumo

when I execute the command :

```
 sumo-launchd.py -vv-c /.../sumo-gui.exe
```

I receive error:

```
Usage: sumo-launchd.py (options)
sumo-launchd.py: error: no such option: --
```

sorry but I'm not very good with these installations
some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you wanted to use arguments `-vv -c ...` instead of `-vv-c ...`. Many argument parsers treat a sequence of individual characters as multiple single-letter arguments (in your case:  `-v`,  `-v`,  `--`, and  `-c`), which is why the argument parser gives this weird error.